# Xcode 4 and cocos2D 1.0.0 beta Uncategorized errors and Info.plist doesn't exist

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, info.plist

I just installed the xcode 4 sdk and the cocos2d 1.0.0 beta template.

I just created a new project with the cocos2d template.
But when I build I got these errors :
(for information my previous projects developed with xcode 3 have the same problem)

warning: couldn't add 'com.apple.XcodeGenerated' tag to '/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build': Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo=0x201dde680 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
error: unable to create '/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates' (Permission denied)
error: unable to create '/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Products' (Permission denied)
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build/Objects-normal/i386
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-dflnzjtztxdgjwhistrvvjxetfrg
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-fqemzerugrwojibbegzkffljkxqs
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Intermediates/xcode4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.build
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Index/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-dbtcglhksokwygezixirqkgfipsr_ast
Unable to create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Index/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-gdirtpasdqzasnclnkzguimarjpd_ast
error: couldn't create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.app: Permission denied
error: couldn't create directory /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xcode4-bswxazfuwbsguiasyatbtlmvbpps/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xcode4.app: Permission denied
The file “Info.plist” doesn’t exist.

Please help !!

Comment: I've also got the problem after upgrading to xcode 4 - Someone please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just experienced the same issue - check the permissions on the directory:

```
/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/
```

In my case it was owned by root (which I suspect was as a result of installing the cocos2d templates before a fresh install of Xcode - but could be wrong). Changing it to be owned by my user fixed the issue, or in your case:

```
sudo chown Benoit /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/
```

Hope that helps.

Nick

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved an issue on my project to :D. Thanks a lot