# Error after Xcode upgrade: couldn't add 'com.apple.XcodeGenerated' tag

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, upgrade

> warning: couldn't add 'com.apple.XcodeGenerated' tag to '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-sakjfljdasklsasadfkj;/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build':
>    Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo=0x22ea133a "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"

I upgrade xcode 3.2 to 4.1

This MyApp worked fine before Xcode upgrade to 4.1

Comment: This link solve my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662132/xcode-4-and-cocos2d-1-0-0-beta-uncategorized-errors-and-info-plist-doesnt-exist/5720905#5720905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running, a window is opend.

I clicked 허용 or 승인 (in English, maybe "permit").

After clicking "permit" key, it works fine with no error.

Answer (score 3):

Clean your build folder! (⌥⇧⌘K)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Running:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Library/Developer
```

worked for me

Comment: just a comment, `~/Library/Developer is the same location`.  Just trying to save peoples finger joints one terminal command at a time ;)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me. This happened to me when I checked out an old branch and then checked back out the new branch and remnants of the old one were still present.

I fixed it by cleaning using git:

git clean -n -f -x -d

Now here's the real command without -n:

git clean -f -x -d